# The [crt] tag needs some clean up

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag wiki exerpt of [crt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crt) is:

> For issues relating to utilizing the c runtime library.

However, it has different meanings in different questions:

1. C runtime library.
2. The certificate type `.crt`
3. The CRT display
4. The Chinese remainder theorem

and possibly others that I don't recognize.

I suggest creating new tags for the first two types (e.g, [c-runtime-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-runtime-library) and [crt-certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crt-certificate). The other two types, I'm not sure, I don't see them with much value.

Comment: Surprisingly few [tag:pascal][+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal+crt)[tag:crt].

Comment: Cathode Ray Tube?